# How can I break up a picture in three segments for separate framing?

Tags: image-quality, crop

I have a wonderful picture of our horse (in portrait) and would love to enlarge it and frame it for my husband. I was thinking of breaking the picture up into three different segments and then framing each one and putting it up on our wall.

What program could I use and how big could I make the picture go before I lose quality to pixelation?

Comment: Hi Carrie, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free program: http://www.gimp.org/

The 3 part probably won't work becouse you need to separate the pices and it would look like someone choped the horse. This kind of efect works if you can have the space between the images and think of the image as if you are seeing it in 3 different windows.

If you want to go:

1) Make a backup of the photo
2) Use the menu Image > Canvas Size > and play with the values

Regarding the size you need like 150ppi for a decent print. 200 ppi is the ideal for a photo.

If your file is 2000px width you can enlarge it lets say (2000/150=) 13.3 inches.

You can risk a bit resampling the photo you will have a bigger photo but a little blurry.

1) Image > Scale > 200%
2) Apply sharpen: Filters > Enhance > Unsharp Mask Play with the values.

And decide the photo size without further rescaling. Just play with the Print Size.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much. I'll give that a go this week. Thanks tons again. Cheers, Carrie

Answer (score 0):

My solution will include Adobe indesign and a free script called comes with Indesign called "Make Grid"

You can find it in `Windows > scripts`will launch the script panel navigate `Application > Samples > JavaScript` and choose `MakeGrid.sjx'

**follow the steps:**

1. place the image you want to split in the Document with the size you want
2. select the image you just place it.
3. run the script from the panel by double click it or rightclick and choose 'Run Script' -- please note that this script location may vary from version to version.

[image]

4. a Dialogue box will appear with some setting ... adjust those setting the way you want your final output.

[image]

5. click ok and review the result

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much. I do not have Adobe, however I will have a look at the costs associated... fingers crossed I can find a free version. Thanks so much again. Cheers, Carrie